# Having A prolem with count():

Tags: php, laravel

ErrorException in Builder.php line 1185:
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

//PostController Code

```
public function index()
    {
      $posts = Post::all();

      return view('posts.index', compact('posts'));
    }




 public function create()
    {
        return view('posts.create');
    }
```

//index.blade.php code

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<ul>

    @foreach($posts as $post)

    <li> {{$post->title}}} </li>

    @endforeach

  </ul>

@endsection
```

Many suggest me to downgrade PHP version ,which i did (basically i downloaded a xampp zip file containg 5.36 version, and i copy past the "PHP" and "Apache" folder to the old xampp, and edited the php.ini file)

Everything was good, but i was on a middle of a project, so when i was trying to access those links, it was giving me an error.

Comment: Where is the `count()` problem?

Comment: I dont know, all i know is php use it to do eloquent, i am not getting it, i did not use any count() method.

Comment: You actually need to upgrade php.  Laravel 5.8 requirement: `"php": "^7.1.3"`

Comment: My laravel version is 5.2. There are two way to doing it, either i have to downgrade my PHP, or update my Laravel 5.2 TO 5.8. As i said ,i am in middle of a project, so updating laravel wont help.

Answer (score 0):

In **index.blade.php** remove extra curly brace from `{{$post->title}}`

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<ul>

    @foreach($posts as $post)

    <li> {{$post->title}} </li>

    @endforeach

  </ul>

@endsection
```

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is still there

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try to use @forelse? It must be happening because your query has no results to show. So, you could try to use:

```
@forelse($posts as $post)

    <li> {{$post->title}}} </li>

@empty

    <li>No data to show</li>

@endforelse
```